# How to start an app in a particular Space (Desktop) in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, spaces

Space behaves differently in Mountain Lion. In Lion, I have four spaces and I can launch an app (say, Safari) in a particular Space (say, Space 3).

How can I do that in Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the application to the correct space manually, then right click the icon in the dock, choose Options and Assign To This Desktop. It will then open automatically there the next time.

[image]